# response()->download() works from postman but not from SPA

Tags: laravel, download, request, response

I have a simple laravel controller action that simply downloads a file:

```
public function show(Product $product, ProductPhoto $productPhoto)
{
    return response()->download(storage_path() . '/app/' . $productPhoto->path);
}
```

This response only works **if I make the request from PostMan**. But **when I make the request from a single page application using axios or fetch**, I get `500 Internal Server Error` Response.

However, If I return anything else from the controller, the response gets sent properly (`200 Ok`)

```
public function show(Product $product, ProductPhoto $productPhoto)
{
    return 'Anything else'; // This works.
    return response()->download(storage_path() . '/app/' . $productPhoto->path); // This doesn't.
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong in that `return response()->download()` statement.

Comment: What is the `500` error?

Comment: In addition to what @thisiskelvin asked for it is worth noting that 500 errors are always server side, so you should be able to dig up the error message in your logs (`storage/logs/laravel-2019-xx-xx.log`) or if you have APP_DEBUG=true it will return in the response data for the request that Axios made (can be inspected in the Network tab in modern browsers)

Comment: Here is a side note, that might not necessarily help with your 500 error, but is worth mentioning. Although you're not showing your JS code, I'm guessing it's something like this `axios.get('/download/path')`. There actually no need for axios to trigger a download. To trigger the download dialog in the browser you just need to set the window location to the download path and it will work automatically `window.location.href = '/download/path'`. It will not navigate away to the download page as some people might expect, it will only trigger the download dialog if the response is correct.

Comment: Here is the response in browser: https://imgur.com/a/CJjY3d8

Comment: @xyz Thanks for the insights. The APP_DEBUG is set to true. But interestingly, I found an exception in log file: `local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::withHeaders()`

Comment: As far as I know, this error in log was supposed to be printed in the response. But instead, I don't even have a response body as you can see in the previous screenshot

Comment: Okay guys, I think I may have detected the source of my problem. In my custom Cors middleware, I am returning  the headers in the following manner:

`return $next($request)->withHeaders([])` This is where the error is thrown

Comment: Cool, good job.